# How can we inject our custom APP code (html code) into shopify product page without using Script tag

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, shopify

I'm trying to figure out how to get my app's html div onto the products page of shopify. I am creating an APP based on quantity breakdown feature using laravel. I need to add HTML code onto product page as shown below.

[image]

**In right, you can see the HTML code just above the ADD TO CART button. I need to do exactly the same.**

As my app will work on different themes, and every theme have its own layout. I don't think using script tag it will work. Please give me a solution to do it without using script tags.

### Please note that I am working with Laravel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I don't think so...its related to implementing own custom code into shopify product page.  I have tried to search about this but I did't find any solution.

Comment: What do you mean your own code? If this is for a single site you can just add it to the product template however you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an App Proxy for one. Or a Script Tag for another. Your choice. Choose the one that makes you happiest.

Comment: As my app will work on different themes, and every theme have its own layout. I don't think using script tag it will work. will you please help me to do it with app proxy? is it a safe method?

Answer (score 0):

1. When a user installs your app, use ScriptTag to add js on the product page
2. Using js, search for the id of the button with text 'Add to Cart' or contain 'Cart'. If the store is using bundle app, it may have an extra button 'Add bundle to Cart'
3. Add your code under Add to Cart button

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but the problem if the product page is already customized and the ID or class is different than you mentioned.
is there any permanent solution to find the button ID or class according to page not only for product page but also for cart page?